Time-series forecasting problem in Python
I am working on a Python project where I have to predict the energy consumption in individual households. My dataset consists of several thousands of households each having a monthly value of the energy consumed over a 2-year period, but only in certain months (01-05), so it's a $10$ point time series per household. Each household has one other time-dependent variable i.e. local humidity/temperature index and several time-independent features both continuous e.g. house size (area), zip code and categorical e.g. resident owns home, resident has children. The task is to predict energy consumption values in future months for each household using this information.
The dataset looks something like this:



house_id
month
year
zipcode
en_cons
weather_idx
size
owns_house
has_children




1
1
2021
12
4.33
19.6
71
0.0
1.0


1
2
2021
12
4.35
17.6
71
0.0
1.0


1
3
2021
12
4.56
12.3
71
0.0
1.0


1
4
2021
12
4.77
15.9
71
0.0
1.0


1
5
2021
12
5.12
19.3
71
0.0
1.0


1
1
2022
12
4.83
19.9
71
0.0
1.0


...
...
...
...
...
...
..
...
...


1
5
2022
12
5.49
18.7
71
0.0
1.0


2
1
2021
44
6.12
17.3
63
1.0
0.0


...
...
...
...
...
...
..
...
...


10000
5
2022
99
5.55
14.3
100
1.0
1.0



I am trying to figure out what ML model to implement in order to predict en_cons for future months and how to include the additional information of the households in the model.
As far as I understand, the typical models used in time-series forecasting such as ARIMA (and its variations) take as input only the timestamp and the value of the quantity to be predicted (they predict the value at a time $t$ based only on the value at earlier times $t-k$). Therefore, it seems that a ML model (maybe something like XGB or LightGBM) that can include all the given information would be the way to go. But I don't know how to actually implement it for my case.
Also, since I want to predict the energy consumption for each individual household, this means that I only have $10$ time points per household to create test and train samples which seems way too few. This also means that I would have to create a separate model for each household. Is that the right way to do it? Is there a way to create sort of a 'global' model using all the data and predict separately for each household?

From your question it seems that you are realtively new in the domain so I will clear some basic things up first before providing a solution.
Time-series data, or formally called temporal data, can be forecasted/modelled via a pretty simple "statistical" approach such as linear regression as well as with a complexer more "temporal data" oriented approach like a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN). I am not familiar with approaches like ARIMA so I cannot comment on that. However first and foremost it is imperative to understand how the system behaves w.r.t the input parameters (formally said, features). For example, consumption could vary with the square of has_children for all we know. This is where domain knowledge comes into play, i.e., using domain-specific constraints to enhance the complexity (or in essence decrease it) so as to improve the learning process. One may in fact need not necessarily insert this domain specific knowledge into the model, since at least a deep enough (complex) neural network should be able to theoretically approximate any function that comes along its way. However, inserting in domain-specific constraints will help to land on to the optimal solution faster (i.e., Convergence) and may improve the quality of results as well.
So, up till now we can hence safely assume, that this is what your goal would be to find the function $y$, denoting the en_cons with the best possible accuracy whereby:
y = f(month, zipcode, weather_idx, size, owns_home, has_children, time)

Now, lets look at the two approaches and their characteristics:
Linear Regression (LR)
It is a pretty simple, easy to understand and easy to implement approach. It can be summed up to the following equation:
$Y = W^T \cdot X + b$
Where, $X$ are your input features, $W$ are their respective weights and $b$ is the bias. However, a pre-requisite is that $Y$ and $X$ should be related linearly to each other. To workaround this, one can inject in polynomials made up of different input features instead of passing them in linearly. So for instance, one could pass in $has\_children^2$ instead of passing it in linearly $has\_children$ to make the approximation work better. Similarly one can also pass in combinations of these polynomials such as $owns\_house \cdot size$ when a product of these two relates to the output in some way. Again, this all can be enhanced given the domain knowledge. Now linear regression, owing to its simplicity (a blessing and a curse) has a pretty definite solution to find out the value of $W$:
$W = (X^TX)^T \cdot (X^TY)$
Which means depending on how "good" on engineers the input features and preprocesses them, they can get pretty good accuracies, however they may then fail to provide good estimates on unseen unknown data, following the same relations between input variables. This is cause LR does not learn the relations and then calculate $W$, but rather simply fits the curve (or primitively said, simply solves a definitive equation with a defined solution) and calls it a day.
Now, LR in itself does not take into account temporal dependence between the points, which in your case, exist. For instance, the consumption of month $5$ could be dependent on that of $4$. To inject this dependency, one can use an approach such as moving averages to capture the temporal dependecy between the data points.
Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN)
These are slightly hard to understand for beginners, but this architecture of neural networks takes into account the temporal dependency between the points and then give out some estimate. Moreover, as is for neural networks in general, they actually learn the relation between the input data, which means that one may not need to intensively engineer the inputs to cater to a domain-specific solution like I discussed above (formally, known as feature engineering). However, even a small amount of it leads to pretty fast convergences.

Therefore, what you would want to use would depend on the amount of time you at hand and the accuracy/generalisability of the solution you desire. On one hand is a pretty straightforward approach, requiring a lot of "engineering" and "hacks" to get the predictions right and offers limited generalisability whereas the other one, even in its simplest form, can lead to fairly good generalisabitily but is however slightly hard to grasp at first.
